# storing sql query results to populate dropdownlist inside formview

Tags: c#, caching, drop-down-menu, webforms, formview

I have a `dropdownlist` of zipcodes.

It is a really large list and takes too long to load from database.  So, first I was looking for the best solution to try and cache or save this data when the website is first loaded so I can use it whenever needed.  I tried a list and dictionary then setting the `datasource` in code behind but it wouldn't let me set the selected value.

It kept telling me that it couldn't bind to a control with no `datasource`.  To make things more difficult the `dropdownlist` is inside a `formview`.

I am just not sure the best way to go about this. I am setting the `datasource` and values in the `formview` created method but my selected value comes from the `formview` `datasource`.

```
 private Dictionary<int, string> CreateZipcodeList()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KlamathAlgaeEntityDevConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    Dictionary<int,string> ziplist = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    //Create CoreEntity Record
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select zipcode.ZipCodeId, zipcode.zip + ', ' + city.name + ', ' + ISNULL(GeographicState.name,'') + ', ' + Country.name as zipstring
                                    from zipcode left outer join City on ZipCode.CityId = city.CityId
                                    left outer join GeographicState on ZipCode.GeographicStateId = GeographicState.GeographicStateId
                                    left outer join Country on ZipCode.CountryId = Country.CountryId
                                    order by country.name, GeographicState.name, city.name",
                                    conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                ziplist.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader["zipstring"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return ziplist;
}

protected void AddressForm_ItemCreated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{


         ((DropDownList)AddressForm.FindControl("Zipcodeddl")).DataSource = CreateZipcodeList();
        ((DropDownList)AddressForm.FindControl("Zipcodeddl")).DataTextField = "Value";
        ((DropDownList)AddressForm.FindControl("Zipcodeddl")).DataValueField = "Key";
        ((DropDownList)AddressForm.FindControl("Zipcodeddl")).DataBind();
        //((DropDownList)AddressForm.FindControl("Zipcodeddl")).SelectedValue = Eval("zipcodeid").ToString();
}
```

This populates the dropdown fine but when I try setting the selected value it says the control is not databound.  This also doesn't store the dictionary anywhere so I need to call the function to load dictionary when ever I need it.

Comment: Please post some code so we know what you have tried

Comment: my query is about 50,000 results so I am beginning to think a dropdownlist isn't the way to go, but I don't know what control is.  Maybe a combobox, dropdownlist with some sort of filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that is way too many records for a drop down.  Why don't you allow the user to enter 5 numberic characters, and then do an search on your Database by that number.  I can't think of any reason you would have to put the entire zip code list in a drop down since no one is going to manually click down to find the one they want.  I don't think it servers a usefull purpose, but if there is one let me know and I will try to figure out a solution.

Thats how the post office does it.

#### Update

To make this work, you would have a TextBox where a user could enter the zip code they think it is.  Give them a button to click to search for that zip code.

Do an sql query to your database looking for that Zipcode.Zip, and if found, bring back all the data you need.

If it is not found what I would do is start removing the last character and do another search with a modified query with "Zipcode.Zip like '%modifiedZipCode%', and bring back the closest 10 or so options, and put those in a drop down menu.

If you remove one digit and the database could not find it you could go as far as you want removing characters, and rerunning the query until you got 10 or however many records you want.  At some point removing digits will become pointless because the user obviously entered an incorrect zip code.

Comment: I agree with you on that. The only issue is that for international zips sometimes they have numbers and letters and people might want to look by country first.  I was looking into cascading dropdowns but I don't want to do full postback on each one and I was reading that an update panel inside a formview doesn't work so well.  I was also thinking I could put the entire zip, city, state, country in a string and try to use a combobox to search and see if it contains what the user entered.  I have seen some custom controls like that but it seems most you have to pay for.

Comment: My main question is, are people going here having no idea what their zip code is, and using your site to figure out a zip code when they have none in mind, or do most people know the zip code before they enter it.

Comment: Its an internal website for salespeople to take phone orders.  They should have it but for some countries its a little complex and well some of our salespeople leave a little to be desired.  Anyway, if I go the route you suggested how would I go about that.  Use a textbox / combobox with a dropdown, then how do I do search after they enter the zip?

Comment: There is another option, although I don't personally like it, but that would be to contain your zip code data in an XML file ServerSide.  Then I would have person entery their country in a combo box, and it and also be able to enter city name, and then there would be a drop down with possible zip codes.

Comment: @user1740003 I updated the answer with how I would do it.  Also, just a friendly note, but I noticed you have asked alot of questions, but don't select the answer for other people to use.  You will get help quicker on this site if you mark questions answered.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Yeah Sorry about that, I am still new to stackoverflow.  I will go back and fix those.  Anyway, thanks for all the help, this website is a life saver.